# Rails - Accidentally dropped my table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Being stupid, and careless, I accidentally dropped my table with contents. How do I re-create that table again in RAils? Tried to run `rake db:migrate` but it didn't create a new table. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run specific migrations regardless of whether or not they have been run.

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20101124121304
```

This runs the up method on the migration created on 11/24/2010 at 12:13:04 PM. Find the migration file that contains the table you need and rerun the migration. That being said, any data from that table is not recoverable.

Comment: I think it's acutally rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20101124121304. Only this worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't recover data, but I'm assuming you just want structure?

Check if you `db/schema.rb` is up-to-date. It should contain a current structure definition of your table.

You can recreate your *entire database* from `db/schema.rb` using `rake db:setup`. I'm not aware of a method that recreates just a single table.

But perhaps you can create a new database using a different name, and copy the structure. Or tediously recreate the table yourself based on what's in `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: I was only using fake data so far, so I didn't care about recovering lost data. I also didn't want to modify my schema file with migrations. Using `rake db:setup` worked to recreate the db structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you `DROP` a MySQL table, you cannot recover that data unless you've made a backup.

Answer (score 0):

This is 2 step process:

1. Create the table only with table_name.
2. Run the below command:

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20220609102335
```